# Sharing live audio to other network devices

Tags: networking, sound, sharing

### The problem

I've got a PC running Ubuntu and another device with speakers. Basically, I would like to be able to play a DVD on my computer (DVD player and monitor are directly connected) but then stream the audio output to other devices within the network. As far as I know, you are able to share folders containing audio files, but those would be 'fixed', they won't change as a stream would do.

### My approaches

- I tried to work out a solution using VLC but I didn't really find a suitable setting...
- There would be a workaround: recording the audio beforehand and share that file then, but that would be (a) quiet a lot of work, (b) not working all the time as my audio/video output could be streamed to my PC as well over the internet in which case I couldn't create a separate file beforehand.

*I would appreciate any kind of idea, approach or suggestion. Thanks a lot for your help!*